# How to access files from your source folder, eclipse

Tags: java

In my project on eclipse I created another source folder to hold an mp3 file. Does anyone know how to access that file. What would the file path be? The reason why I did this is so this file would be included with my project when I turn it into a jar file and run it on different computers. If anyone has a better idea on how to do this feel free to contribute!

Comment: Since it is in your source you should be able to just put "sound.mp3" and have it come up. If that does not work you can always create an instance of a new file, assign it the file you want and use System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());

Answer (score 0):

right click on your project > properties  > resources > location

if you want to programmatically go there generally eclipse starts jvm with working directory set to base of project so you can navigate from `new File(".")`

Answer (score 0):

Check the getResourceAsStream method from class Class: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_getresourceasstream.htm

Answer (score 0):

In spring:

```
ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

final Resource resource  = 
    resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:com/XX/XX/" + filename);
```

Comment: Sorry to hassle you, but what would the classpath:com//XX/XX/ look like...could someone give me an example?

Comment: suppose you save the files within your project in a package like com.audio.files, also com:/XXX could be change for any folder in your classpath

Answer (score 0):

in Eclipse, right-click on your project and select "Properties".
With "Resource" selected, it shows "Location:" which is the path to your project.
Let's say if you added a folder to your project called **Audio**, then you could access a mp file like this:

```
new File(".\\Audio\\MyAudioFile.mp3")...
```